# Combine several single line text files into a single line text file in Unix

Tags: unix

I have three single line text files foo1.txt, foo2.txt and foo3.txt. After I used cat foo1.txt foo2.txt foo3.txt > foo.txt, the foo.txt contains three lines which I do not want, I want a single line joined from each of the files.
I tried `cat foo.txt | sed 's/\n//g' > new.txt`, but new.txt is identical to foo.txt.
I tried `tr '\n' '' < foo.txt > new.txt`, the same, new.txt is identical to foo.txt.
I tried `paste -sd "\0" foo1.txt foo2.txt foo3.txt > foo.txt`, but foo.txt still contains three lines.
I tried `echo $(cat foo1.txt foo2.txt foo3.txt) > foo.txt`, although foo.txt contains a single line, but all the spaces are gone.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have them in one file, the `tr` you were looking for was `tr -d '\n'`

```
$ cat foo.txt
1 1 11 1    1
1 1 11 1 122
1 1 1     1 1 133
$tr -d '\n' < foo.txt > new.txt
$ cat new.txt
1 1 11 1    11 1 11 1 1221 1 1     1 1 133$
```

Note though that this also removes the last line feed on the file.

`awk 'ORS="";1'` will do this from the individual files, but will also remove the trailing line feed, as it sets the output record separator to nothing, then prints each line it reads, e.g.

```
$ cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
1 1 11 1    1
1 1 11 1 122
1 1 1     1 1 133
$ awk 'ORS="";1' 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
1 1 11 1    11 1 11 1 1221 1 1     1 1 133$
```

Note my terminal just chiling at the end there. If you want an ending line feed you can add `END{print"\n"}`, e.g.

```
$ awk 'ORS="";1;END{print"\n"}' 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
1 1 11 1    11 1 11 1 1221 1 1     1 1 133
$
```

If you want a space or something between each file's lines you can set the ORS to whatever that is and remove the 1, however that will leave a trailing character of whatever you set it to, so you'd have to swap it back to a line feed after, e.g.

```
$ awk 'ORS="|"' 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt | sed 's/|$/\n/g'
1 1 11 1    1|1 1 11 1 122|1 1 1     1 1 133
```

**EDIT** In a comment it was asked what the awk command actually meant:

- `ORS="";` - This sets awk's Output Record Separator, which is by
  default a '\n' to nothing. The ORS Is used between rows, so this causes rows from our files will be
  placed into one line.
- `1;` - awk works on blocks of code like `condition? {code}` with the
  default behavior  being `print` if the block is not present, so this
  is an easy way of writing `{print}`.  Note that the `ORS=""` acts as
  a conditional statement on a block too, though in this case the
  assignment of nothing is seen as false, so nothing happens aside from
  the ORS being set.  This is why when we change it to something like
  `ORS="|"` we can remove the 1, because the assignment of a value ORS
  is seen as true, and would execute the default behavior of `{print}`
- `END{print"\n"}` - Blocks prefaced with END are only executed after
  all lines of all files are read, so this adds back the trailing line
  feed we removed by changing ORS.

Comment: Thanks zzevannn, I used nawk 'ORS="";1;END{print"\n"}' since my awk does not work. Would you mind to explain what 'ORS="";1' means?

Comment: @pat - added some explanation to the answer, hopefully that helps. If this worked for you please don't forget to up vote and accept

Answer (score 0):

I just tried:

```
echo $(cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)
```

This seems to remove the line endings between the file outputs.

About your spaces being gone, I don't have this type of behaviour:

```
Prompt> cat test.txt
version = 1.203 
Prompt> echo $(cat test.txt test.txt test.txt)
version = 1.203 version = 1.203 version = 1.203
```

Comment: but, as the OP _says in the question_ "all the spaces are gone" -- multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space.

Comment: @StephenP: I've edited my answer. It seems there's some unexpected behaviour, as the `echo $(cat ...)` is the right way to go.

Comment: Hi @Dominique — try with a file that has the line `version    =    1.203` where there are 4 spaces on each side of the equal sign. (hahaha the spaces weren't preserved in this comment, even though it's in backticks). `echo` itself would preserve the spaces, it is the interpretation of the command that collapses them; in that sense this is expected behaviour. You need to quote the command to avoid that. Try `echo "$(cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)"`

Comment: Test it after `echo "*" > test.txt`.